# How to change one field in a structure that is part of an array in MongoDB using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following records in a collection:

```
{ 
    id : id_value,
    streams : [
        { a : a_value, b : b_value, c : c_value },
        { a : a_value, b : b_value, c : c_value }, ...
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to change the **c_value** of a particular entry in the **streams** array. I've been using a two step process of doing this, pulling out an entry from the **streams** array, creating a new entry and adding it back to the **streams** array. This works, but doesn't seem the most efficient way of accomplishing this. Is there a better approach that I can use? Below is the code that I'm currently using:

```
db.users.update({id:user},
    {$pull : {streams : {$and : [{a : a_value}, {b : b_value}]}}},
    {w:1}, cb);

new_entry = { a : old_a_value, b : old_b_value, c : new_c_value} 

db.users.update({id:user},
    {$addToSet : {streams : new_entry}}, {w:1}, cb);
```

Thank You,
Gary

Answer (score 1):

If more than one field is being matched in the array record, then $elemMatch is required.

When matching just one field of an array record, then below works:

```
db.users.update(
    { "id": user, "streams.a": a_value},
    { "$set" : { "streams.$.c": new_c_value } },
    { "w": 1}, cb);
```

When matching more than one field of an array record, then $elemMatch is required as shown below:

```
db.users.update(
    { "id": user, streams: {$elemMatch : {a:a_value, b:b_value}},
    { "$set" : { "streams.$.c": new_c_value } },
    { "w": 1}, cb);
```